# Quiero hacer una validación de formulario pero no me sale en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario en el que tengo un campo donde el usuario introduce su numero de telefono y le obligamos a que tiene que empezar por +34 seguido de 9 dígitos(12 digitos en total son los que debe tener ese campo), pero luego cuando cambio a +31 por ejemplo me lo recoge como si fuera +34, esto es usando un

```
<input type="name">
```

Esta es la función que estoy usando en Javascript

```
if (telefono != '+34' & telefono2 < 12) {
        evt.preventDefault(); 
        alert('El número del teléfono debera empezar por +34 y tener al menos 12 dígitos ');
        
      }
```

Comment: (telefono != '+34' **&&** telefono2 < 12), te falta un & ahí

Comment: @Benito Dudo que con eso pueda solucionarlo, no hay ni siquiera un .length o algo por el estilo, la solución está en utilizar una **expresión regular** para lo que pide es una expresión muy simple, por otro lado **input type="name"** no creo que exista un tipo con ese valor.

Comment: @NikolaTesla Ha puesto un trozo MUY breve del código, quiero suponer que telefono2 ya guardaba la longitud del string... Por otro lado, efectivamente sería mejor usar una expresión regular, pero la gente que está aprendiendo a programar no suele conocerlas. De todas maneras, usar un operador bitwise en ese if desde luego no va a darle el resultado esperado aunque las variables sean correctas.

Comment: @Benito-B Tu que llevas mas tiempo en el sitio, ¿Será prudente responderle con la respuesta correcta? o ¿Hay que esperar a que el usuario intente algo mas?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios detalles en tu código que hay que corregir:

1.- El valor en el atributo `type` esta incorrecto, si bien el navegador te lo muestra de manera correcta, es por que no deja de ser un input como tal.

```
<input type="name"> <!-- ¡ESTO ES INCORRECTO! -->
```

2.- Te dejo un enlace en el que podrás investigar sobre los tipos de `inputs` que existen **te será de gran utilidad:**

[Tipos de input HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Tipos_input_HTML5)

3.- Si lo que deseas es ingresar un numero telefonico, te recomiendo utilizar en el atributo `type` el valor `tel` quedando tu input de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="tel" name="numTel" id="numTel" />
```

4.- La siguiente validación es **incorrecta** por donde lo veas:

```
if (telefono != '+34' & telefono2 < 12) {
   evt.preventDefault(); 
   alert('El número del teléfono debera empezar por +34 y tener al menos 12 dígitos ');
            
}
```

5.- Estas diciendo: que si lo que ingresa el usuario es diferente de **+34** haga algo, por lo que si tu ingresas lo siguiente **+34123456789** Esto, para lo que tu estas pidiendo es un numero valido pero en tu if es incorrecto ya que

**+34** es diferente de **+34123456789** esta de mas hablar de tu otra condicion ya que en ningun momento validas la longitud de lo que ingrese el usuaurio.

6.- Lo que yo te recomiendo es utilizar una **expresion regular** que en tu caso seria una expresion muy simple:

```
let regex = /\+34[0-9]{9,9}/gi;
```

7.- En la expresion anterior, estamos diciendo que el numero debe de tener forzosamente
**+34** seguido de cualquier numero entre el **0 y 9** solo 9 digitos despues de **+34**

8.- Te dejo un enlace para que profundices mas en el tema, y puedas aprender un poco mas sobre expresiones regulares:

[Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

[RegExp JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)

9.- Te muestro un ejemplo practico, con **código comentado** para que puedas solucionar tu practica.

```js
/*
  ALMACENAMOS EN UNA VARIABLE
  NUESTRA EXPRESION REGULAR
*/
let regex = /\+34[0-9]{9,9}/gi;

/*
  ALMACENAMOS EN UNA CONSTANTE
  NUESTRO FORMULARIO QUE TIENE 
  COMO ID #miFormulario
*/

const miFormulario = document.querySelector("#miFormulario");

/*
  A NUESTRO FORMULARIO LE AGREGAMOS 
  UN EVENTO DE TIPO SUBMIT
*/

miFormulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  /*
  ALMACENAMOS EN UNA VARIABLE
  EL VALOR QUE TIENE 
  NUESTRO INPUT DE TIPO TEL
  QUE TIENE COMO ID numTel
*/

  let numeroTelefonico = document.querySelector("#numTel").value;

  /*
  PROBAMOS NUESTRA EXPRESION 
  REGULAR ANTES ALAMACENADA
  EN LA VARIABLE regex
  Y ADEMAS VALIDAMOS LA LONGITUD
  DEL NUMERO TELEFONICO
*/

  if (regex.test(numeroTelefonico) && numeroTelefonico.length <= 12) {
    alert("¡NUMERO VALIDO!");
  } else {
    alert("¡ERROR!");
  }

  /*
  EN LA VALIDACION ANTERIOR
  ESTAMOS DICIENDO QUE
  SI LA EXPRESION SE CUMPLE
  Y ADEMAS EL NUMERO TIENE
  12 DIGITOS MUESTRE UN
  ALERT QUE DIGA ¡NUMERO VALIDO!
*/

});
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
```

```html
 <form id="miFormulario">
      <input type="tel" name="numTel" id="numTel" />
      <button>Comprobar</button>
    </form>
```